# How to get IST time zone in Android

Tags: java, android, timezone

I am new to android application development , I am developing an app that is going to run in india only, I want to get the time of asia/kolkata timezone without using "joda" library
 I used the following code but i didn't get expected output

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
Log.d("Time zone","="+tz.getDisplayName());
```

I want the time in hh:mm:ss format

Comment: @Biffen OMFG. That's literally the first thing I thought (exactly) when I read the title. That's awesome.

Comment: Use a SimpleDateFormat: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I am not good in english , any one pls help

Comment: @DerGolem I could not get the correct time

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();

        calender.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));

        System.out.println(calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE) +  ":" + calender.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
    }
}
```

This is a full program that gets the time from the timezone in Asia/Calcutta. It displays hours, minutes and seconds!

Comment: thanks it worked , your code is simple and easy @Bas

Answer (score 3):

You do not speak english, so lets talk Java. ;-)

```
 String format = "hh:mm:ss";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
 System.out.format("%s\n", sdf.format(new Date()));
```

IST is India Standard Time or UTC/GMT + 5:30 h. I took this from the android API-Documentation mentioned in a comment of Der Golem (+1) and from the following link: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india/kolkata