# How to get local date and time in android?

Tags: android, date

I want local date and time of my android phone. I have tried the following code :

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
String output=calendar.getTime()+"";
```

And i am getting `output : Sat Mar 26 11:15:38 GMT+00:00 2016` and this is wrong actual date and time was "26th March 2016" and time was "16:46", i am getting date proper but time wrong and even got GMT timezone instead IST timezone. Is that because of Timezone if yes please let me know other solutions. Thanx in advance

Comment: Android doesn't support the three-letter time zone IDs, other than UTC and GMT. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416343/how-to-get-ist-time-zone-in-android).

Comment: ok. is there anyway i can convert this GMT+00:00 into GMT+05:30??

Comment: Did you check the post I linked?

Comment: Yes and i am trying it

Comment: If you don't want to do it that way, have a look at [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)). It explains how to do it with raw offsets.

Comment: Thanx Mike it worked :)

Comment: No problem. You should be able to mark that post as helpful to close out your question now. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Kind of related, but there still seems to be a lot of confusion around "time in milliseconds". See my explanation on that -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57220021/2102748. I know I stumbled upon this first, and then looked up time in millis later on.

Answer (score 0):

I Use this -

```
public String getTime(){
       return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
```

You can also try

```
return DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

For different patterns and more details, please look at the android documentation for date and time

Comment: Thanx for replying and I did and i am getting date perfectly but time value wrong. I got "26/03/16 11:25:00" instead of "26/03/16 16:58:00"

Comment: Try this-  Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();  If even this comes wrong, please check your phone for Time setting

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
 String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
```

Comment: Thanx for replying I have no issues with date the only things is that i am getting wrong time

Answer (score 0):

This code works best for me:-

```
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
        hours = cal.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );  
        if ( hours > 12 ) hours -= 12;  
        minutes = cal.get( Calendar.MINUTE );  
        seconds = cal.get( Calendar.SECOND );  

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");  
        Date date = cal.getTime();  
        timeString = formatter.format( date );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
     Locale.getDefault());
```

Use this to set the variable to your time zone or you can specify Continent/Country to be more specific forexample:

```
dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/India");
Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String currentDate = ddateFormat.format(c);    //You can use this as your output date
```